# subtract seconds from epoch timestamp inside spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How do I subtract seconds from epoch timestamp using spark sql?

I use the following using spark sql to convert epoch to date:

```
date(from_unixtime((cast(timestamp as DOUBLE)) / 1000))
```

I want to subtract 60 seconds before I convert epoch to date

Comment: Why not subtract  after converting ?

Comment: There is no function to subtract in spark sql after converting. The only function there is "date_diff" which takes input only in days.

Comment: how about `date(from_unixtime((cast(timestamp -60*1000 as DOUBLE)) / 1000))`

Answer (score 0):

```
date(from_unixtime((cast(timestamp -60*1000 as DOUBLE)) / 1000))
```

Comment: Spark `unix_timestamp` returns value in seconds, not milliseconds:  https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@unix_timestamp(s:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column

Answer (score -1):

you can use minus() function. But the data should be in compatible format.

Comment: Could you please edit your answer and add the code that the OP would have to use? As far as I know spark SQL does not have a `minus()` function. Could you add a link to where we can find it in the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/)

Comment: Okay My Bad. I didn't follow that. However, given the operation, can be performed in regular Dataframe and minus() function can be operated. for example..   col("ts").cast("Long").minus(60)